# Almacenar el id del objeto en un campo manytomany

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Tengo en django un modelo usuario con un campo:

```
wallets = models.ManyToManyField(Wallet)
```

y un objeto Wallet con otros campos. Actualmente almaceno en el campo wallets del usuario los nombres de los objetos Wallets asignados al usuario. ¿De qué forma puedo almacenar el id y que en el formulario siguiente se siga mostrando el nombre?

```
wallets = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Wallet.objects.all(),to_field_name="name",required=False)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer Django lo hace de forma interna, por lo que me he abstraido del proceso y puedo almacenar objetos con distinto nombre y tratarlos como si fuesen diferentes.